# Why is 'didset' called on a property when I set the property of that property?

Tags: ios, swift

In this code when the text changes, `titleEditingChanged` is called (as expected). But when it executes the line

```
investment?.title = sender.text!
```

it calls the `didset{}` of `Investment`. 
Why?

```
class InvestmentCell: UITableViewCell {

    var investment: Investment? {
        didSet {
            // setup UI elements from class properties
            textField.text = investment?.title
            valueField.text = investment?.value?.description
        }
    }

    @IBAction func titleEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        investment?.title = sender.text!
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueField: UITextField!
}
```

Comment: Is `Investment` a class or a struct?

Comment: This is normal behavior. The same happens, when you append an item to an array.

Comment: `didSet` and `willSet` are *property observers*. You can ready about them in the [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is called because `Investment` is probably a struct, not a class.
In Swift structs are value types, not reference types as classes.
So, structs are not "mutable in place".

It means that whenever you change a struct property a new struct object is allocated to replace the current one, the current object data is copied to the new one except for the changed property that will contain the new value set.

Remember that the compiler does not let you change a struct property whenever you initialize a struct object with a `let` command (with a class you can do it).

That explains why the observer is called whenever you change a struct property. Once a new struct object is allocated to replace the current one, it will now be stored in another memory block, so its value will be changed and the `didSet` observer will be called.

**PS:** It will not happen if you define `Investment` as a class instead of a struct.

Comment: I did as you suggested and changed struct Investment to class Investment, and it had the desired effect.

Comment: Also be aware that standard types like String, Array, Dictionary and Set are all value types. So having a property of these types also makes the didSet observer called on any access on the property. (That gave me a lot of headache)

Answer (score 15):

Property observers of *value types* (e.g. structures) are called also when an underlying property of the type instance is set; simply since the *value of the instance itself is updated*. The same *does not hold for reference types*; as long as the reference itself is not mutated, the property observer will not be called (i.e., the reference itself can be considered the value of reference types).

From [Language Guide - Properties - Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) we read:

> Property observers observe and respond to *changes in a property’s
>   value*. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is
>   set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current value

---

To verify the above, consider the following example:

```
/* reference type */
class InvestmentC {
    var title: String = "Foo"
}

/* value type */
struct InvestmentS {
    var title: String = "bar"
}

class InvestmentContainer {
    var investmentC : InvestmentC {
        didSet {
            print("did set a property of 'InvestmentC' instance (ref. type)")
        }
    }

    var investmentS : InvestmentS {
        didSet {
            print("did set a property of 'InvestmentS' instance (val. type)")
        }
    }

    init() {
        investmentC = InvestmentC()
        investmentS = InvestmentS()
    }
}

/* Example: property observer called only when setting a property
            of the value type instance 'investmentC'              */
let foo = InvestmentContainer()
foo.investmentC.title = "foobar" // prints: nothing
foo.investmentS.title = "foobar" // prints: "did set a property of 'InvestmentS' instance (val. type)"
```

---

Hence, we can infer that your custom type `Investment` is a value type (a structure), and the `didSet` property observer of the instance `investment` of this type (in your `UITableViewCell` subclass) will be called even if you only set/update underlying properties of `investment`. If you'd like to avoid this, change `Investment` into a reference type (class), in which case the `didSet` property observer will only be changed if the `investment` instance *itself* is set/updated.

Comment: This is a great answer but in the end I chose to give the tick to Jorg B Jorge because I found it more concise and quicker to understand the issue. But your answer was more comprehensive and also helped me to understand and solve the issue. Investment was a struct and I did change it to a class which I found the more transparent way to code it. Thanks.